# Recommended books for enterprise application interface design

Tags: interaction-design, guidelines, usability, business-application

I've been reading a lot on UX lately with the intention of improving the user experience on the custom applications we develop. Most of the resources I used are targeting informational websites. I would like suggestions on resources that I can use that target enterprise & portal applications.

Answer (score 3):

I'd say one of the better ones for application design is [About Face 3](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0470084111).  A lot of it spends time on interaction design for desktop apps, as opposed to the web (at least in version 2).  You can't go wrong with Alan Cooper's work.

Comment: I've also found Designing the Moment http://amzn.to/lRxS37 very informative.

Answer (score 0):

Not a book, but the yearly reports of [Nielsen Norman Group](http://www.nngroup.com) for intranets would help a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Some books on specific topics that apply to enterprise aplications are the following:

- Form design:

  - [Web Form design: filling in the blanks](http://rosenfeldmedia.com/books/webforms/) by Luke Wroblewski.
  - [Forms that work](http://www.formsthatwork.com/) by Caroline Jarrett.
- Search analytics:

  - [Search Analytics for Your Site](http://rosenfeldmedia.com/books/searchanalytics/) by Louis Rosenfeld.